# Find the locus of the feet of the perpendicular drawn upon any tangent to the ellipse $\frac {x^2}{a^2} + \frac {y^2}{b^2} = 1$ from either focus.

Tags: conic-sections, tangent-line

Find the locus of the feet of the perpendicular drawn upon any tangent to the ellipse $\dfrac {x^2}{a^2} + \dfrac {y^2}{b^2} = 1$ from either focus.

My Attempt:
Let the tangent to the ellipse be
$y=mx\pm \sqrt {a^2m^2+b^2}$
Here the slope of tangent is $m$ so the slope of the perpendicular drawn from focus to the tangent is $-\dfrac {1}{m}$.

[Equation of the locus of the foot of perpendicular from any focus upon any tangent to the ellipse ${x^2\over a^2}+{y^2\over b^2}=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775323/equation-of-the-locus-of-the-foot-of-perpendicular-from-any-focus-upon-any-tange) 
This follows a geometrical approach but I'm looking for an analytical solution.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775323/equation-of-the-locus-of-the-foot-of-perpendicular-from-any-focus-upon-any-tange

Comment: It's simply axillary circle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equation of the locus of the foot of perpendicular from any focus upon any tangent to the ellipse ${x^2\over a^2}+{y^2\over b^2}=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775323/equation-of-the-locus-of-the-foot-of-perpendicular-from-any-focus-upon-any-tange)

Comment: @Andrei The OP explicitly said that question did not help him because it did not give an analytic solution, only a geometric one.

Comment: @almagest Note that the request for analytical approach came after the link to the geometric approach was posted

Comment: Your attempt so far consists of writing down two definitions. That’s a start, but I think you can get farther than that. How about developing the equation of the perpendicular through a focus now?

Comment: See my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059564/property-of-ellipse/2060603#2060603) for the visualization, your required locus is the auxiliary circle (green).