# Polar curve of a conic with respect to a circle

Tags: conic-sections

Given a circle of center $O$ and radius $r$, I know that the polar curve of a conic with respect to the circle is, in general, a conic. Now, in a work about Kepler's laws, I found that: if the center of the circle coincide with a focus of the conic, the polar curve is a circle. Someone know how we can prove this claim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't read the books suggested in the other answer, but I found a fairly simple proof - apologies if it is the same given there.

Suppose we have an ellipse with focus $F$ and a circle $c$ (pink in figure below) centred at $F$. To construct the polar line of a point $P$ on the ellipse, with respect to $c$, we can construct point $P'$, the circular inverse of $P$ with respect to $c$: the polar is then the line perpendicular to $FP$ at $P'$. The polar of the ellipse is the envelope of all the polars of $P$, as $P$ varies on the ellipse.

To construct the point on the envelope lying on the polar line of $P$, we can consider another point $Q$ on the ellipse, near to $P$: as $Q\to P$, the intersection of the polar lines of $P$ and $Q$ tends to a point $M$ on the envelope.

To find $M$, it is equivalent (but easier) to consider point $Q$ on the tangent at $P$ to the ellipse. If $Q'$ is the inverse of $Q$, then points $FP'Q'$ lie on a circle, which is the inverse of the tangent, and $M$ is the other endpoint of the diameter through $F$ (because $\angle FPM=\angle FQM=90°$). This means that $M$ is the inverse of point $H$, which is the projection of $F$ on the tangent.

But it is easy to prove ([see here for a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1257504/255730)) that the locus of the projections of a focus on the tangents to an ellipse is its auxiliary circle, that is the circle having the major axis of the ellipse as diameter (solid green in the figure). **Hence the polar of the ellipse, which is the locus of $M$, is indeed a circle: the inverse of the auxiliary circle with respect to $c$ (dashed green in the figure).**

[image]

Comment: Grazie! Very nice !!

Comment: Very interesting, once more !

Answer (score 2):

$19$th and early $20$th century textbooks for the win!

You can find a synthetic proof in [Russel, *Pure Geometry*, pg 93.](https://archive.org/details/dli.ernet.523171/page/93/mode/2up)  You may have to go to earlier parts of the book to get lemmas and definitions.

This is part of a chapter on the polar reciprocation of conics in both circles and conics.  (Polar reciprocals are what we now call polar curves.)

A variant of the proof is in [Pickford, *Projective Geometry*, $\S 187$](https://archive.org/details/elementaryprojec00pickrich/page/214/mode/2up).

There is a different proof at [Casey, *Analytical Geometry*](https://archive.org/details/treatiseonanalyt00jcas_602/page/n201/mode/2up), $\S 125$ (pg 184).  Again, it may require referring to earlier material.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is just what I was looking for  :)